# How to stop the login server?

Tags: xorg, gdm, lightdm

With GDM removed in Oneiric, what command can I replace from the old command?

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop
```

I need to install an nvidia .run file and cannot figure out how to stop the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking the natty method was

```
sudo service gdm stop
```

For oneiric lightdm has replaced gdm - therefore to stop you would use

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Comment: `sudo stop lightdm` [also works](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65856/how-does-one-exit-the-x-server/65867#65867).