# How do I stop X server?

Tags: command-line, nvidia, xorg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one exit the X server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65856/how-does-one-exit-the-x-server)

So it looks like I need to install Nvidia manually, and to do so, I need to stop the X server completely.

After pressing `[CTRL]+[ALT]+[F1]`, I tried this command at the prompt:

```
sudo service gdm stop
```

... but all I get is "unknown service:" and the NVIDIA install script won't run.

This also doesn't work:

```
sudo gdm stop
```

It just takes me a login screen.

How can I completely kill X in 11.04?