# How can I set my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to boot to console without GUI?

Tags: 12.04, server, boot, gui, console

So I installed Ubuntu server to run some tests on a VM. For various reasons I couldn't get a specific DEB file, and instead of using a shared folder I decided it would be a good idea to install ubuntu-desktop so I can run Firefox and grab the file directly from the web.

Now, every time I boot my machine I get the graphical interface, but I have no reason for it since I'm running tests with the LAMP server.

I tried this

[How do I boot into console mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70188/how-do-i-boot-into-console-mode)

And this

[Possible to install ubuntu-desktop and then boot to no GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74645/possible-to-install-ubuntu-desktop-and-then-boot-to-no-gui)

If anyone has any idea for a solution, I'd appreciate it.

BTW: I thought about simply uninstalling ubuntu-desktop, but I feel like I might need it in the future, so, I really just want to disable the GUI.

EDIT:

While this solution is not perfect I realized, it works for now:

On the [How do I boot into console mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70188/how-do-i-boot-into-console-mode?lq=1) question, user Michael K mentions that:

"
Okay another way would be to disable the lightdm service in init:

```
/etc/init/lightdm.conf
```

in there there is a section like this:

```
start on (filesystem
and started dbus
and (drm-device-added card0 PRIMARY_DEVICE_FOR_DISPLAY=1
or stopped udev-fallback-graphics))
```

"

While this worked perfectly, I can't access the GUI with the `startx` command - the system just crashes. And I guess I'll need to uncomment the section to load startx.

Considering the fact that I want to keep the server running for as long as possible, having to restart it every time I want to log in the GUI is kinda unproductive.

EDIT2:

I guess it's possible simply to kill the GUI ( [How to stop the Unity Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73767/how-to-stop-the-unity-desktop) ) when I log in the system, it's still counter productive, but it works too.

EDIT3:

Michael K's reply worked fine. I just realized that to call the GUI I need to run `lightdm` and not `startx`

Comment: Maybe you could delete the Unity + 2D sessions and see what happens: `cd /usr/share/xsessions`, `ls`, then delete all of them: `rm x.desktop` `rm y.desktop` ...etc.

Comment: I've got gnome.desktop / gnome-shell.desktop / ubuntu-2d.desktop / ubuntu.desktop - I should remove them all?

Comment: Yes. Although I am not sure what could happen, it's only a guess - so it might destroy everything, or it could fallback into a prompt.

Comment: Meh, who cares? It's a VMBox, and I already managed to learn a lot =p. Anyways, I deleted them all, and I still get the GUI.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That instructions works like a charm to me in my Ubuntu 12.04.1

Change (edit) in /etc/default/grub file:

From:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

To:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

Now you must update the grub configs:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And its done!
After reboot, to start the gui just login and type:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

Comment: In case 'startx' doesnot work try 'sudo start lightdm'

Answer (score 3):

On the [How do I boot into console mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70188/how-do-i-boot-into-console-mode?lq=1) question, user Michael K mentions that:

"
Okay another way would be to disable the lightdm service in init:

```
/etc/init/lightdm.conf
```

in there there is a section like this:

```
start on (filesystem
and started dbus
and (drm-device-added card0 PRIMARY_DEVICE_FOR_DISPLAY=1
or stopped udev-fallback-graphics))
```

"

Then to call the GUI I just need to run `lightdm`.