# How to kill and to start the X server?

Tags: xorg

In 12.04 How do you kill the X server from the command line and from the GUI interface and how do you start it from the virtual terminal?

Comment: If you just want to kill the X server, you can enable the Ctrl+Alt+Backspace  key combinations on “Options” of keyboard layout settings.

Comment: related http://askubuntu.com/questions/65856/how-does-one-exit-the-x-server

Answer (score 42):

One way to restart an instance of the X server is to run (from the commandline)

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

For Ubuntu 15.04 and later:

```
sudo systemctl restart lightdm.service
```

and for Kubuntu 15.04 and later:

```
sudo systemctl stop sddm.service
```

Comment: lightdm? I thought gdm was for GNOME, kdm for KDE, xdm for XFCE and lightdm for LXDE! and to stp it from the gUI?

Comment: lightdm is the default for 12.04, I'm not sure when it was made the default perhaps in 11.10?

Comment: restarting lightdm doesn't kill Xorg. Only an instance of it.

Comment: lightdm starts only one instance of Xorg, so restarting lightdm should close the only open Xorg instance, unless you're doing something much more complicated.

Answer (score 21):

On 12.04, you can restart the server with the shortcut keys: <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: What a strange combination!. Print??. It has no logic;  and what would "(Right alt) + (Print Screen) + K" be in an Apple keyboard? I have right command and no print

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key has more info on it if you want to understand the logic behind it. printscreen is the same key as  sysrq(System Request).

Comment: @semi: "printscreen is the same key as sysrq" - not on my keyboard. `sysreq` is the same key as `delete`.

Comment: What happens if you hit right alt + sysrq + k on your key layout? Does it still work?  I just know internally they always call it the magic sysrq key, so it seems odd that it would become the magic printscreen key just because of another layout being used.

Comment: Nothing happens on my machine (fresh install of 13.10).

Comment: In order for this to work you need to run this command once: `sudo echo kernel.sysrq=1 > /etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf`

Comment: With the netbook I just tried it on, I needed to use the left Alt rather than the right (which is Alt Gr).

Answer (score 13):

In Ubuntu 14.04:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then run:

```
sudo service gdm stop
```

*or*

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

… depending on your display manager.

**NOTE:** To recover use `startx`, alternatively replace the `stop` with `start` in either of the above commands.

Answer (score 8):

Kill : `xkill -a`. `-a` means it will kill all display instances. For more information run `man xkill`.

Run : `xinit`.
Also `startx` but this command is to start an instance and not the server itself. For more information run `man xint` and `man startx`.

I don't believe it's possible to kill Xserver from GUI, and even if it were, it would not be the right way to do it.

Comment: Wouldn't that kill all individual windows, which is not what the user wants? For example I don't want to kill all my firefox windows, I want to restart the visualisation.

Comment: The user said: "kill and start the X server". That seems to be *exactly* what he wants. It's not about restarting gnome-shell.

Comment: Doesn't work for me from tty: `Unable to open display ""`

Comment: This is more generalized than restarting lightdm services in case you don't have a display manager. UPVOTE!

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 22.04 (and a few previous versions) you can add a hotkey to your gnome session to kill the x server. Install gnome-tweaks via `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` and then open it (logo button and then "tweaks" and enter) then goto "Keyboard & Mouse" -> "Additional Layout Options" -> "Key sequence to kill the X server" -> "Ctrl+Alt+Backspace"

Answer (score 0):

On more recent versions of Ubuntu (e.g. 22.04) which use Gnome and systemd, you can use:

```bash
$ sudo systemctl restart gdm.service
```