# How to kill the X server and end up with a CLI?

Tags: xorg

Is it possible to kill the GUI and end up with a CLI since the GUI runs on the top of the shell?

I have check the question below
[How to kill and to start the X server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131051/how-to-kill-and-to-start-the-x-server)

Magic keys restarted the GUI and I ended up with the login menu but not a CLI
I am using Ubuntu 12.04 , I dont want to use virtual terminal I just want to prove to myself that the GUI runs on top of the shell and I can always exit the GUI to the shell

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To shut down your X session type in the command line:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

So you will end up in the virtual terminal #7. You then can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to get a login prompt. For terminal #7 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) there is no tty started because it's meant for the x server.

**Edit:**

If you want to end of in a shell, then create a file called `/etc/init/tty7.conf` with content:

```
# tty7 - getty
#
# This service maintains a getty on tty7 from the point the system is
# started until it is shut down again.

start on runlevel [23] and not-container

stop on runlevel [!23]

respawn
exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty7
```

After creating this file reboot the system, and then when you perform `sudo service lightdm stop` you will end up in a login shell.

Comment: does this mean the x server does not run on the top of a shell?

Comment: It does run on top of a virtual terminal (also virtual console), but not on top of a shell (bash, sh, csh, tcsh, ...). But you can start a shell in a virtual terminal, like in #1 - #6. When you stop the X session there is nothing to enter commands unless there is a shell started, like in #1 - #6.

Comment: @user1298069 see my edit

Comment: thanks but how do they do it in BackTrack then? you login with your user name and password into bash then you start X server and GUI with "startx". btw you are a great help, thanks

Comment: Np, you can do the same in ubuntu, when you login in the shell then you can type `startx` and your desktop will appear. `startx` is like lightdm  a display manager, but non-graphical.

Answer (score 0):

That solution brings your "GUI" back because you have the lightdm service running. Run `sudo stop lightdm`. That command will stop your lightdm service, kill X server and bring the console.

Once in the console, if you want to start your X11 session again, run `sudo start lightdm`.

Comment: I've tried this but then like chaos explained in his answer I have to log into an other virtual terminal to start lightdm. How do I achieve something like the case of BackTrack, you start the GUI with "startx". I want to exit the GUI to the shell, thats all