# How to turn off Unity in 12.04 LTS?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one exit the X server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65856/how-does-one-exit-the-x-server)

So I need to turn off Unity GUI and get back to the text user interface, how do I do that in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + F1?

Comment: What do you mean by "turn off"?

Comment: duplicate of something, but i think it's more "what desktop environments are available"

Answer (score 1):

use Ctrl + Alt + F1  for  text user interface

and When you want to back Unity GUI then use Ctrl + Alt + F7

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use

> `sudo apt-get remove unity unity-2d`

Comment: That would still leave the X server running and wut not, not really recommend. Besides disable does not mean removal in most cases.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to edit your run levels, it's not too easy in Ubuntu, but [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man7/runlevel.7.html) is a great reference page with all the information you need for 12.04 lts.

I've you're looking to save system resources for server running, or just want the pure CLI experience, you should switch to a much more open distro like Fedora, Debian, cENTos, or RHEL.

Or if you just want access to a command line, just use Terminal!

Comment: Why Ubuntu can't be in "open distro" list? Fedora is just like Ubuntu with gnome-shell interface. So, what is the key point?