# how to close x server?

Tags: 12.04, installation, drivers, nvidia, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install latest NVIDIA drivers by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66328/how-do-i-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-by-hand)

nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Thu Dec 13 21:28:38 2012
installer version: 304.64

PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

nvidia-installer command line:
    ./nvidia-installer

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
-> The file '/tmp/.X0-lock' exists and appears to contain the process ID '1200' of a runnning X server.
ERROR: You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before installing.  For further details, please see the section INSTALLING THE NVIDIA DRIVER in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.

please help me fix this.

Comment: Please refer http://askubuntu.com/questions/228579/how-do-i-start-ubuntu-without-x-server for a solution

Answer (score 1):

To install the nvidia drivers manually you need to run the nvidia installer with the X server closed. So first drop to console

sudo stop lightdm

And then go to the directory where you have the installer and run it. When you are done try

sudo start lightdm