# No more icons on my desktop

Tags: launcher, icons

Ubuntu 14.04. I have 2 user accounts. This problems appears only for one of it.
I have no more icons on my desktop, neither the launcher, just the desktop picture. Right click still works, so I can access system settings.
When using gnome, everything works perfect.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information please. What were you doing before this happened - software? installing? tweaking? system details? etc. etc. Thank You

Comment: It happened suddenly, while normal usage. The PC was shut down, then for one user account that strange thing happened. For other user accounts it works OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your screen resloution in system settings to a lower one than currently selected.

I've had such a problem before when using a projector, that could only handle 720p. The settings were 1080p by default and the "overflow" was just cut off, so I could only see the center of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Ty restarting the GDM.
To restart GDM, switch to Ctrl+Alt+F1, login, andt ype the command

sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart

Then when you get the [OK], switch back with Ctrl+Alt+F7.

Comment: sudo: /etc/init.d/gdm: command not found

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart unity
Get terminal using ctrl+alt+T
Run this command

```
 sudo service gdm restart
```

Comment: gdm: unrecognized service

Comment: check this.http://askubuntu.com/questions/65856/how-does-one-exit-the-x-server It will probably solve your problem