# How can I install CUDA 9 on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: cuda, 17.10

Ubuntu 17.10 comes with CUDA 8 which relies on clang 3.8 
(e.g. see [this blogpost](https://medium.com/@at15/install-nvidia-cuda-on-ubuntu-17-04-823300ab7bcc)).

However, I'd like to install CUDA 9 and rely on GCC if possible. How can I do this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**Installation of NVIDIA driver 384**

First we install a fresh Ubuntu 17.10 on a computer with an NVIDIA GPU and select "Install third-party software" during the process. Alternatively, we can add the graphics drivers repository manually:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```

Then we install the most recent NVIDIA driver using apt:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-384 nvidia-384-dev
```

We verify the installation by running:

```
nvidia-smi
```

We should see an output which lists the NVIDIA 384 driver and our discrete NVIDIA GPU - similar to summarized table below:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.90                 Driver Version: 384.90                    |
|                                                                             |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   0  Quadro M500M        Off  | 00000000:06:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   48C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    943MiB /  2002MiB |     26%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

**Preparation for installing of CUDA 9 + SDK**

We install a number of build/dev packages which we require later:

```
sudo apt-get install g++ freeglut3-dev build-essential libx11-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev
```

We notice that the default gcc/g++ version on 17.10 is `7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3)`
:

```
gcc -v
```

CUDA 9 requires gcc 6. Thus, we install it:

```
sudo apt install gcc-6
sudo apt install g++-6
```

Note that the default gcc version is still `7.2`; can be checked by running `gcc -v` again.

**Installation of CUDA 9 + SDK**

From the [CUDA Toolkit Archive](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive), select one of the "runfile (local)" installation packages to download a version of CUDA 9, such as

```
wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.0/Prod/local_installers/cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux-run
```

Make the downloaded file executable and run it using sudo:

```
chmod +x cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux-run 
sudo ./cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux-run --override
```

We install CUDA with the following configurations:

```
You are attempting to install on an unsupported configuration. Do you wish to continue?
y
Install NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 384.81?
n
Install the CUDA 9.0 Toolkit?
y
Enter Toolkit Location
[default location]
Do you want to install a symbolic link at /usr/local/cuda?
y
Install the CUDA 9.0 Samples?
y
Enter CUDA Samples Location
[default location]
```

Set up symlinks for gcc/g++:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-6 /usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-6 /usr/local/cuda/bin/g++
```

**Test the CUDA 9 installation using the SDK**

Build your favorite CUDA sample and run it:

```
cd ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-9.0_Samples/5_Simulations/smokeParticles
make
../../bin/x86_64/linux/release/smokeParticles
```

You may like to set up gcc/g++ symlinks after the cuda install.

Comment: Been stuck on this issue for a bit. Running 17.10, trying to install CUDA 9. I'm having an issue on step 2: nvidia-smi `NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver.`  Ran `lspci | grep -i nvidia` says I have a GeForce GTX 760. `mokutil --sb-state` shows SecureBoot disabled. Ran `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`, ran your install command for 384, and ran `dpkg -S nvidia-smi`
nvidia-384: /usr/lib/nvidia-384/bin/nvidia-smi. Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume you tried a reboot after installing nvidia-384, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, many reboots. I'm also getting another error from modprobe: `modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:832 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='nvidia_384'`

Comment: Hey got `nvidia-smi` to work! I formatted my HD and reinstalled the OS. Also, I'd like to point out you're missing a step: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and `sudo apt update` must be run before `sudo apt install nvidia-384 nvidia-384-dev`

Comment: @ClarkKent, I assume you did not tick "Install third-party software" during the installation, right?

Comment: When setting up the OS? Didn't do it either time.

Comment: I had to do either `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-6 /usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/gcc
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-6 /usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/g++` or `sudo ./cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux-run --override` as author below recommends to install successfully without compiler conflict

Comment: I vaguely remember that I probably used the --override option. In any case, it cannot hurt, so I updated the description above.

Comment: the two commands to add the symbolic links for the gcc 6 compilers have to be done after installing cuda, because /usr/local/cuda does not exist before installing

Comment: Helper a lot! The only thing I did in another way - created symlinks after cuda installation at the very end.

Comment: Prior to running `cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run`, how did you create the soft links (`ln -s`)? Did you manually create the cuda folder?

Comment: Also works with Cuda 9.1.

Comment: Will this also work for Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Also compare with http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#axzz4VZnqTJ2A

Comment: Read this for installing Nvidia drivers https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers [frequently updated]

Comment: Those who encounter unsupported compiler error while installing cuda toolkit make gcc 6 as the default compiler by creating symlink.

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-6 /usr/local/bin/gcc
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-6 /usr/local/bin/g++

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, see https://gist.github.com/andyweizhao/639e94b60c166f57964aafedeb465e90

Answer (score 5):

Getting this installed took more time than I would like to admit, and while the above answer is a good template, I had some additional steps required for my fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10:

## blacklist nouveau

```
sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Add the following:

```
# this one might not be required for x86 32 bit users.
blacklist amd76x_edac 

blacklist vga16fb
blacklist nouveau
blacklist rivafb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist rivatv
```

## Update initramfs disk

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

## Stop gdm3

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm3 stop

sudo init 3
```

## Get content

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-384 nvidia-384-dev
sudo apt-get install g++ freeglut3-dev build-essential libx11-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev

nvidia-smi
```

## Get the package

```
wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.0/Prod/local_installers/cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux-run
```

## Run with --override to override compiler choice

```
chmod +x cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux-run 
sudo ./cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux-run --override
```

After installing the package, I would get errors with nvidia-smi, so I suggest running the command again to verify it works. When I had issues, I would purge nvidia* and re-get it.

```
nvidia-smi
```

Comment: Some people may need to stop `lightdm` instead of `gdm3`, see https://askubuntu.com/a/65867/422690

Comment: My screen gone by running `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm3 stop`!

Answer (score 1):

I followed the accepted answer (@ubashu) and everything went well (if not exactly the same, the instructions would lead to the correct path). I would only had the export to Path (as specified also on https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions)

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}} 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64\ ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

After that you can use nvcc -V to check if the install really went well.