# CUDA symlinks not working

Tags: nvidia, gcc, cuda, 17.10, symbolic-link

I'm trying to install CUDA on Ubuntu using this guide by @B0rk4:

[How can I install CUDA 9 on Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967332/how-can-i-install-cuda-9-on-ubuntu-17-10)

The relevant section is to create a symlink for gcc & g++:

```
sudo apt install gcc-6
sudo apt install g++-6
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-6 /usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-6 /usr/local/cuda/bin/g++
```

When I follow these steps I get an error:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/local/cuda/bin/g++': No such file or directory
```

**How can I create these symlinks?**

Thanks in advance - I would comment on the linked page, but I'd need 50 rep to do so.

Comment: If the target directory does not exist already, you may need to create it first: `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/cuda/bin`

Comment: Thanks - I've done that for both gcc & g++ but the CUDA install still fails with an error: Toolkit:  Installation Failed. Using unsupported Compiler.